# accept() timeout or error?

Tags: c, linux, sockets

Is it possible to determine if accept() returns -1 because of a timeout or if there was another error?

errno is set to 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) when accept times out. Is that the only error accept can produce?

Comment: The man pages for accept() clearly state the errors that are possible

Comment: `accept` can produce several errors, take a look to [ERRORS list](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/accept.html) at the end

Comment: If it is not one error, it would be "another error", no?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [man page of `accept()`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/accept). says:

> On success, these system calls return a nonnegative integer that is a
>   descriptor for the accepted socket. On error, -1 is returned, and
>   errno is set appropriately.

It has list of error numbers as well.

> In addition, network errors for the new socket and as defined for the protocol may be returned. Various Linux kernels can return other errors such as [..] ETIMEDOUT.

---

**Is it possible to determine if accept() returns -1 because of a timeout or if there was another error?**

After checking return code as -1 you can check error number and based on that decide because of which error your accept() get failed.

**errno is set to 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) when accept times out. Is that the only error accept can produce?**

No this is not the only error. You can see all error on Man page.